.net running on kestrel cannot start BackgroundService in staging/production environment
I have created a QueuedHostedService extending BackgroundService following official docs here. This runs just fine on development mode and I am able to step into/debug the task passed to the background service when the controller passing the task executes.
However, this doesn't seem to happen on Staging mode. I could replicate this not only on my staging environment but also on my local using the following launchSettings.json
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55612/",
      "sslPort": 44366
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging",
        "CONSUL_HTTP_SSL_VERIFY": "0"
      }
    },
    "MyApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging",
        "CONSUL_HTTP_SSL_VERIFY": "0"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55612/;https://localhost:44366/"
    }
  }
}

My app runs on kestrel server I believe (new to .net - we run the dll with dotnet command), not IIS for which the solution exists here but I couldn't find any for kestrel.
This has been my analysis. Please let me know what's wrong or how I can setup kestrel to let BackgroundService run all the time with the lifecycle of the app.

Could you find the publish files and run cmd /c "set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging && dotnet project_name.dll" in cmd tool?

@JasonPan Yes, this is the way to build for prod and I tried it on local; able to reproduce the same issue

Hi Aakash, the launchSettings.json file is only used for vs2022, when we excute the command dotnet project_name.dll, it will read the environment variables automaticly.

And if you want to run the app on kestrel, we can use builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>         {             serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(5000); // http         });. The correct usage of asp.net core with background service, you can check this thread.

The app is running by default on kestrel listening to 5000. The link you've shared is to start a window service; what I am trying to do is to have a parallel running background service as another process apart from my main .net app server.
